# Angular - ag-grid - add columns dynamically

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I need to add some columns to my Ag-grid in 2 cases. Other cases i just need base columns.

So in constructor I declare my grid like this :

```
this.gridOption.columnDefs = [
  {
        headerName: 'Admission date',
        field: 'admissionPlannedDate',
        cellRendererFramework: DateCellRendererComponent,
        cellRendererParams: (params) => {
          return (params.data.admissionPlannedDate ? {dateFormat: 'dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm'} : {dateFormat: ' '});
        },
        cellStyle: function (params) {
          return (params.data.admissionPlannedDate < new Date() ? {color: 'red'} : {});
        }
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Lastname',
        field: 'lastName',
        cellStyle: function (params) {
          return (params.data.edsId === null ? {color: 'orange'} : {});
        }
        },
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Sex',
        field: 'sex',
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Birthdate',
        field: 'birthDate',
        cellRendererFramework: DateCellRendererComponent,
        cellRendererParams: (params) => {
            return (params.data.birthDate ? {dateFormat: 'dd.MM.yyyy'} : {dateFormat: ' '});
        },
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Localisation',
        field: 'localisation',
      }
];
```

Then In my ngOnInit, in some conditions i need do add columns to my ag-grid.

I tried this following :

```
 this.gridOption.columnDefs.push(
                {
                  headerName: 'Block',
                  field: 'block',
                }, {
                  headerName: 'SDS/Hosp',
                  field: 'sdsOrHosp'
                }
              );
console.log(this.gridOption); //I see the new columns here so the add worked but i don't see them visual in my grid
```

also tried

```
 this.gridOption.columnDefs.push({ headerName: 'Bloc', field:'block'});
 this.gridOption.columnDefs.push({ headerName: 'SDS/Hosp', field:'SDSorHosp'});
```

Someone has an idea ?
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't just push new values to `columnDefs`, I mean for sure you can but the flow doesn't work like that on `ag-grid` case.

So to achieve your goal (dynamically add\remove `columnDefs`) you need to use [`setColumnDefs(colDefs)`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#columns) method

> **`setColumnDefs(colDefs)`**  Call to set new column definitions into the grid. The grid will redraw all the column headers, and then redraw all of the rows.

So logically you just need to create the new array of columns and then call `this.gridOption.api.setColumnDefs(...)`

Comment: Do you know if I can add to my gridOption 2 others column with hide: true and then set hide: false in certain conditions ?

Comment: Yes, You can do that to set hide property

Answer (score 3):

If the columns you want to add dynamically is fixed and you want to hide/unhide these columns based on some conditions you can use the Hide property with a callback.

hide: true

Comment: when i do this following 
this.gridOption.api.getColumnDef('key').hide = false;
it doesn't work, the column is still hidden

Comment: Probably the simplest approach concerning this matter for me, rather than dynamically adding/removing columns